# Are there any difference between "of" and "about" in the context?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

•Please, tell me about the new school .

•Please, tell me of the new school.

Comment: What context did you find them in and what research have you already done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please tell me about the new school* is a request for a description of the school. It might be a parent asking for information, or someone asking a new pupil how they are experiencing life there.

To *tell someone of* something usually means to inform them of its existence.

> Mr Smith told me of a new school that is going to open in September.

Comment: Can i use both interchangeably?

Comment: No - I've just explained the difference between them. (_Tell someone of_ can be used in the sense _describe_, but usually in the context of storytelling rather than everyday conversation - _The old sailor told us of the foreign lands he had visited_.)

Comment: Can i use it formally?

Comment: It would mark you out as a non-native speaker if you did!